# API upgrade issue for login

Tags: facebook, authentication, upgrade

We have developed a Facebook app on our product for couple years, and we used the Graph API 1.0 and FQL for the queries. Recently we've got an email from FB saying that the API 1.0 and FQL will not support anymore after 4/30.
Now we are upgrading to the API 2.0 and found an issue regarding to the login method.
Our product is an embedded device and we develop the FB app without using a browser but pure api calls to the server. FB have gave us a method for login (auth.login) and also the procedure of how to use it. Now the question is does this auth.login method still valid after 4/30?

Answer (score 0):

No, it won't work after April 30th 2015 I guess. See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/overview/v2.3
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/v2.3

Comment: Actually, the auth.login is a hidden API. The API documents on the developer site were never mentioned about this auth.login call. I just wonder if this call being removed or not after 4/30.

Comment: It's not *hidden*, it's part of the long-deprecated REST API... https://web.archive.org/web/20110813114253/http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/#login/auth-methods

Comment: So, if you're using non-official or private APIs, and Facebook granted you access to them, then you should also contact them directly about your issue. StackOverflow is not the FB helpdesk. Facebook already announced the REST API as deprecated in August 2014: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_1_deprecations

Comment: I saw a link on FB's developer site and it directs me here. so I thought the FB guys may answer the question.
Thanks, anyway~